# How to run effect plot inside of a R function

Tags: r

**Update:** Previous title was `Is there any specific way to pass data frame as an argument to a function?` but it was not right question according to brilliant guys here. Original post is below.

When I ran following function with `somefunc(sleepstudy)`,

```
somefunc<-function (dataLme) 
{
 library(effects)
 library(lme4)

 fm8 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days|Subject), dataLme,
      REML = 0, verbose = TRUE)

 plot(effect("Days",fm8))
}
```

I got an error.

```
Error in plot(effect("Days", fm8)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'plot': Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'dataLme' not found
```

But if I manually executed

```
library(effects)
library(lme4)
fm8 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days|Subject), sleepstudy,
    REML = 0, verbose = TRUE)
plot(effect("Days",fm8))
```

I didn't get any error.

I thought R passes by value meaning copying whole object content to the function argument. But it looks like I was not entirely right. Can anyone explain what is going on?

Comment: I don't think the issue is R's argument passing semantics, I think the issue is that `effect` is trying to `eval` the model fitting call in the wrong place. Or at least, a place that causes it to not work when run inside a function.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta Days. Sorry for typos. I fixed it in my question. Thanks!

Comment: @joran I see. How did you figure it out that fast? :-) Oh, well. I guess it's time to contact the author then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Thomas `options(error=recover)` is useful for debugging.  It can help identify these types of things quickly.

Comment: I used `traceback` which narrowed the problem back to `eval(cl)` inside of (non-exported function) `mer.to.glm`. If you step through, you'll see that changing the environment argument in `eval(cl)` seems to fix the problem.

Comment: @joran If it's not too much trouble, could you create an answer with yout findings? That will also help others. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A (hacky) workaround is to assign `dataLme` into the global environment, where `effect()` will be able to find it:

```
library(effects)
library(lme4)

somefunc <- function (dataLme) {
    ## Assign to a symbol that's unlikely to be in use in .GlobalEnv
    ## (and make sure this function cleans up after itself!)
    assign(".TeMpVaR", dataLme, envir=globalenv())
    on.exit(rm(.TeMpVaR, envir=globalenv()))

    fm8 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days|Subject), .TeMpVaR,
         REML = 0, verbose = TRUE)    
    plot(effect("Days",fm8))
}

somefunc(sleepstudy)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is only a partial answer, but I did want to document my testing procedure. I mainly wanted to show that the issue is particularly with the `effects` package rather than with the `lme4` package (which I maintain, and which has encountered these sorts of problems as well: most such problems are fixed in the development version of `lme4`, but some persist in the stable version, installed as `lme4.0` on my system ...)

```
library("effects")

showpkgs <- function() names(sessionInfo()$otherPkgs)
somefunc<-function (dataLme, pkg="nlme")  {
    require(pkg,character.only=TRUE)
    on.exit(detach(paste("package",pkg,sep=":"),unload=TRUE,character.only=TRUE))
    if (pkg=="nlme") {
        fm8 <- lme(Reaction ~ 1 + Days,random=~Days|Subject, dataLme)
    } else {
        fm8 <- lmer(Reaction ~ 1 + Days + (1 + Days|Subject), dataLme, REML = 0)
    }
    plot(effect("Days",fm8))
}
```

The error occurs whether we use stable `lme4`, development `lme4`, or the older `nlme` package

```
data("sleepstudy",package="lme4")
showpkgs()
somefunc(sleepstudy)  ## nlme
showpkgs()  ## warning about unloading nlme namespace due to glmmADMB dep. (??)
somefunc(sleepstudy,pkg="lme4.0")  ## lme4-stable
showpkgs()  ## failure to remove Matrix/warning message
somefunc(sleepstudy,pkg="lme4")    ## lme4-devel
showpkgs()  ## leaves RcppEigen, Rcpp loaded as well
```

I took a bit of a look at the `effects` package, and a simple universal fix is not immediately obvious.  Changing the relevant `eval(cl)` lines to `eval(cl,envir=environment(formula(mod)))` works for *development* `lme4`, but not for stable `lme4` or `nlme` ...